# Unable to find `../config/paths` and `../config/env`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, electron

I am trying to convert React.js web app to desktop app through Electron. Please find the error trace, scripts/start.js, and package.json. When I comment out `require('../config/env');` it starts giving same error on `const paths = require('../config/paths');`

start.js

```
        'use strict';

        // Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
        process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'development';
        process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';

        // Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
        // ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
        // terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
        process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
        throw err;
        });

        // Ensure environment variables are read.
        require('../config/env');

        const fs = require('fs');
        const chalk = require('chalk');
        const webpack = require('webpack');
        const WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
        const clearConsole = require('react-dev-utils/clearConsole');
        const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
        const {
        choosePort,
        createCompiler,
        prepareProxy,
        prepareUrls,
        } = require('react-dev-utils/WebpackDevServerUtils');
        const openBrowser = require('react-dev-utils/openBrowser');
        const paths = require('../config/paths');
        const config = require('../config/webpack.config.dev');
        const createDevServerConfig = require('../config/webpackDevServer.config');

        const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);
        const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

        // Warn and crash if required files are missing
        if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
        process.exit(1);
        }

        // Tools like Cloud9 rely on this.
        const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
        const HOST = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';

        if (process.env.HOST) {
        console.log(
          chalk.cyan(
            `Attempting to bind to HOST environment variable: ${chalk.yellow(
              chalk.bold(process.env.HOST)
            )}`
          )
        );
        console.log(
          `If this was unintentional, check that you haven't mistakenly set it in your shell.`
        );
        console.log(`Learn more here: ${chalk.yellow('bitLyLink')}`);
        console.log();
        }

        // We attempt to use the default port but if it is busy, we offer the user to
        // run on a different port. `choosePort()` Promise resolves to the next free port.
        choosePort(HOST, DEFAULT_PORT)
        .then(port => {
          if (port == null) {
            // We have not found a port.
            return;
          }
          const protocol = process.env.HTTPS === 'true' ? 'https' : 'http';
          const appName = require(paths.appPackageJson).name;
          const urls = prepareUrls(protocol, HOST, port);
          // Create a webpack compiler that is configured with custom messages.
          const compiler = createCompiler(webpack, config, appName, urls, useYarn);
          // Load proxy config
          const proxySetting = require(paths.appPackageJson).proxy;
          const proxyConfig = prepareProxy(proxySetting, paths.appPublic);
          // Serve webpack assets generated by the compiler over a web sever.
          const serverConfig = createDevServerConfig(
            proxyConfig,
            urls.lanUrlForConfig
          );
          const devServer = new WebpackDevServer(compiler, serverConfig);
          // Launch WebpackDevServer.
          devServer.listen(port, HOST, err => {
            if (err) {            
              return console.log(err);
            }
            if (isInteractive) {
              clearConsole();
            }
            console.log(chalk.cyan('Starting the development server...\n'));
            openBrowser(urls.localUrlForBrowser);
          });

          ['SIGINT', 'SIGTERM'].forEach(function(sig) {
            process.on(sig, function() {
              devServer.close();
              process.exit();
            });
          });
        })
        .catch(err => {
          if (err && err.message) {
            console.log(err.message);
          }
          process.exit(1);
        });
```

package.json

```
      {
    "name": "utility-core",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "main": "public/electron.js",
    "homepage": "./",
    "dependencies": {
      "autoprefixer": "7.1.6",
      "axios": "^0.18.0",
      "babel-core": "6.26.0",
      "babel-eslint": "7.2.3",
      "babel-jest": "20.0.3",
      "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
      "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
      "babel-runtime": "6.26.0",
      "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
      "case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin": "2.1.1",
      "chalk": "1.1.3",
      "concurrently": "^4.1.1",
      "css-loader": "0.28.7",
      "dotenv": "4.0.0",
      "dotenv-expand": "4.2.0",
      "electron-is-dev": "^1.1.0",
      "eslint": "4.10.0",
      "eslint-config-react-app": "^2.1.0",
      "eslint-loader": "1.9.0",
      "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "2.39.1",
      "eslint-plugin-import": "2.8.0",
      "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "5.1.1",
      "eslint-plugin-react": "7.4.0",
      "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
      "file-loader": "1.1.5",
      "fs-extra": "3.0.1",
      "html-webpack-plugin": "2.29.0",
      "jest": "20.0.4",
      "jquery": "^3.4.1",
      "mdbreact": "^4.15.0",
      "object-assign": "4.1.1",
      "papaparse": "^4.6.0",
      "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "3.2.0",
      "postcss-loader": "2.0.8",
      "promise": "8.0.1",
      "raf": "3.4.0",
      "react": "^16.4.1",
      "react-dev-utils": "^5.0.1",
      "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
      "react-file-reader": "^1.1.4",
      "react-router-dom": "^4.2.0",
      "react-spinners": "^0.4.6",
      "resolve": "1.6.0",
      "style-loader": "0.19.0",
      "sw-precache-webpack-plugin": "0.11.4",
      "universal-cookie": "^3.0.4",
      "url-loader": "0.6.2",
      "wait-on": "^3.2.0",
      "webpack": "3.8.1",
      "webpack-dev-server": "2.9.4",
      "webpack-manifest-plugin": "1.3.2",
      "whatwg-fetch": "2.0.3"
    },
    "scripts": {
      "start": "node scripts/start.js",
      "build": "node scripts/build.js",
      "test": "node scripts/test.js --env=jsdom",
      "electron-dev": "concurrently \" cross-env BROWSER=none npm run start\" \"wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron .\"",
      "electron-pack": "build -c.extraMetadata.main=build/electron.js",
      "preelectron-pack": "npm run build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
      "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
      "csv-loader": "^3.0.2",
      "electron": "^1.8.8",
      "electron-builder": "^20.44.4",
      "electron-installer-windows": "^2.0.0",
      "electron-packager": "^8.7.2"
    },
    "jest": {
      "collectCoverageFrom": [
        "src/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}"
      ],
      "setupFiles": [
        "<rootDir>/config/polyfills.js"
      ],
      "testMatch": [
        "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,mjs}",
        "<rootDir>/src/**/?(*.)(spec|test).{js,jsx,mjs}"
      ],
      "testEnvironment": "node",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
        "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
        "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|mjs|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
      },
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "[/\\\\]node_modules[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|mjs)$"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": {
        "^react-native$": "react-native-web"
      },
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "web.js",
        "js",
        "json",
        "web.jsx",
        "jsx",
        "node",
        "mjs"
      ]
    },
    "babel": {
      "presets": [
        "env",
        "react-app"
      ],
      "plugins": []
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
      "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "author": "Zain Ul Abideen",
    "license": "ISC",
    "build": {
      "extends": null,
      "appId": "com.example.utility-core",
      "files": [
        "build/**/*",
        "node_modules/**/*",
        "./public/electron.js"
      ],
      "directories": {
        "buildResources": "assets"
      }
    }
  }
```

Error

```
    D:\Import Utility\fc-import-utility\utility-core>npm run electron-dev

    > utility-core@0.1.0 electron-dev D:\Import Utility\fc-import-utility\utility-core
    > concurrently " cross-env BROWSER=none npm run start" "wait-on http://localhost:3000 && electron ."

    [0]
    [0] > utility-core@0.1.0 start D:\Import Utility\fc-import-utility\utility-core
    [0] > node scripts/start.js
    [0]
    [0] internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:613
    throw err;
    [0]     ^
    [0]
    [0] Error: Cannot find module '../config/paths'
    [0] Require stack:
    [0] - D:\Import Utility\fc-import-utility\utility-core\scripts\start.js
    [0]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:610:15)
    [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:526:27)
    [0]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:666:19)
    [0]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:16:16)
    [0]     at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Import Utility\fc-import-utility\utility-core\scripts\start.js:30:15)
    [0]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:759:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:770:10)
    [0]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:628:32)
    [0]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:555:12)
    [0]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:822:10)
    [0]
    [0] npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.17134
    [0] npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\HP\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "start"
    [0] npm ERR! node v12.2.0
    [0] npm ERR! npm  v3.8.6
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    [0] npm ERR! utility-core@0.1.0 start: `node scripts/start.js`
    [0] npm ERR! Exit status 1
    [0] npm ERR!
    [0] npm ERR! Failed at the utility-core@0.1.0 start script 'node scripts/start.js'.
    [0] npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    [0] npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the utility-core package,
    [0] npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    [0] npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    [0] npm ERR!     node scripts/start.js
    [0] npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs utility-core
    [0] npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    [0] npm ERR!     npm owner ls utility-core
    [0] npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    [0]
    [0] npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    [0] npm ERR!     D:\Import Utility\fc-import-utility\utility-core\npm-debug.log
    [0]  cross-env BROWSER=none npm run start exited with code 1
```

Comment: config/env.js defines the local paths. If you move start.js, you have to implement that functionality yourself.

Comment: > If you move start.js 
But I haven't moved it anyway.. @DovRine